# C++ undefined reference when creating an object

Tags: c++, undefined

I am new to C++ and have just created a separate class file in my program. There are three files, main.cpp, Cal.h, and Cal.cpp. When I create an object of Cal in the main.cpp file, I get this error: undefined reference to Cal::Cal()

Im quite puzzled by this. Any help will be apreciated. Thanks.

Here is the source files:
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cal.h";

using namespace std;

Cal c;

int main()
{


return 0;
}
```

Cal.h:

```
#ifndef CAL_H
#define CAL_H


class Cal
{
    public:
    Cal();
    int add(int a, int b);
    int sub(int a, int b);
    int mul(int a, int b);
    int div(int a, int b);
};

#endif // CAL_H
```

Cal.cpp:

```
#include "Cal.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Cal::Cal()
{

}


int Cal::add(int a, int b){


return 0;
}

int Cal::sub(int a, int b){
return 0;
}

int Cal::mul(int a, int b){
return 0;
}

int Cal::div(int a, int b){
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need compile all the source files together, or (preferably) link the object files together after you've compiled them.

Comment: You forgot to compile and link `Cal.cpp` with your program.

Comment: They are already linked. Now, I also started getting a message like this: .text+0x20 undefined reference to `main'. Main is clearly defined above.